# How to obfuscate Kotlin Multiplatform code?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

To obfuscate Kotlin code we use the isShrinkResources = true property in the build.gradle file. But for the KMP library, I get the following exception:
com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: Resource shrinker cannot be used for libraries.

I have isShrinkResources set to true in my base App, yet my KMP library seems to not be obfuscated. Is this expected? Seems like a security oversight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isShrinkResources` is not for obfuscation. `isMinifyEnabled` is for obfuscation.  Read more here https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code

Library code doesn't get obfuscated but app code would obfuscate all the code it contains. Libraries would provide `proguard-rules` to make sure unintended code doesn't get obfuscated.